# Silverlight ZOrder doesn' work for me in Bing control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, bing-maps, z-order

I'm trying to make my popup widget to be on top in a map but setting Canvas.ZOrder doesn't help.

Here is XAML:

```
<m:Map x:Name="MainMap"
            Margin="0,6,3,3"
            ZoomLevel="{Binding MapZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}"
            CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed"
            CredentialsProvider="{Binding BingCredentialsProvider}"
            UseInertia="True" 
            Mode="Road" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource WorkLayerData}}">
                <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas
                            m:MapLayer.Position="{Binding Location}">
                            <Button                                
                                Width="{Binding PushpinWidth}" Height="{Binding PushpinWidth}"
                                Margin="{Binding PushpinMargin}"
                                Style="{StaticResource LooklessButtonStyle}"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedPushpinChangedCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                Cursor="Hand">
                                <Ellipse
                                    Width="{Binding PushpinWidth}" Height="{Binding PushpinWidth}" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding IsGPSDataRecent, Converter={StaticResource BoolToGreenRedBrushConverter}}" StrokeThickness="1">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceId}" />
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </Button>

                            <!-- Show black dot over actual GPS point -->
                            <Ellipse
                                Width="10" Height="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
                                Margin="-5,-5,0,0"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />

                            <Border
                                Width="200"
                                BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5"  Color="#FF000000" Opacity="0.5" ShadowDepth="2" />
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource TrackedAssetControlTemplate}" />
                            </Border>
                        </Canvas>                                               
                    </DataTemplate>
                </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </m:MapItemsControl>
        </m:Map>
```

I tried to set ZIndex on a border but no luck.
Here is how it looks when IsSelected = true (see other dots with ZIndex higher on top)

[image]

Comment: ZIndex is a relative value that affects only children of the same Panel. So setting it on some child of the Canvas inside the item DataTemplate would be pointless. Where exectly did you set it? I can't see it in your XAML.

Comment: I tried to set it on a Border surrounding ContentControl, it's not in XAML as I removed it. Where in my example I should do it so it takes effect?

Comment: You may set it in code behind on an item container. You may get the container for an item by the MapItemsControls' [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx).

Comment: It's MVVM, I'd rather not do anything in codebehind. Is there anything I can do in current XAML? Or via binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bring an item in a MapItemsControl to front it is necessary to set the ZIndex of the item container. You can do that in code behind by retrieving the item container from the MapItemsControl's [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

In case you don't want that, you could apply an attached helper property to the top-level container (the Canvas) in the DataTemplate for your map items. As this Canvas is the direct child of the item container, the helper property would have to set the ZIndex of the visual parent of the Canvas. If that sounds weird, here is the code for the attached property, in a helper class called MapItem:

```
public class MapItem
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ZIndexProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ZIndex", typeof(int),
            typeof(MapItem), new PropertyMetadata(ZIndexChanged));

    public static int GetZIndex(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.GetValue(ZIndexProperty);
    }

    public static void SetZIndex(DependencyObject obj, int value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ZIndexProperty, value);
    }

    private static void ZIndexChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // set ZIndex on parent of obj
        Canvas.SetZIndex((UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj), (int)e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

In your DataTemplate you may now bind the helper property to one of your VM properties, perhaps by using an appropriate binding converter:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MapItemDataTemplate">
    <!-- setting the helper property MapItem.ZIndex on Canvas
         sets the Canvas.ZIndex property on the item container -->
    <Canvas local:MapItem.ZIndex="{Binding ...}">
        ...
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hm.. I think about it and it may not solve my problem. I have Dot (small circle) and actual panel that becomes visible as part of the same data template. Giving this template ZOrder will do it for ALL items on map and it will be the same problem. Should I place panel in separate canvas and give different ZOrder to panel and dot?

Comment: Setting ZIndex this way will bring the actual item to front, i.e. above all other items. Hence the dot and the Border on top will be placed on top of everything else in the MapItemsControl. Of course the binding source property would have to be set exclusively for the "front" item.

Comment: I see. So I have to manipulate specifi item's ZOrder. Thanks a lot for helping me on this one. I will mark as answer, but I actually solved it differently (easier IMO). I put another MapItemsControl with popup panels only. So first one draws dots and second one draws invisible panels. Works great!

Comment: A second MapItemsControl is of course a simple solution here. You may however come back to setting the ZIndex when your map items become larger and they have significant overlap, perhaps when you display a label at each dot. Then you may want to bring the currently selected (or so) item to front.